# Check box list not appearing in Spring MVC annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement dynamic check box list in Spring MVC with annotations. So, I tried this one out:

In home.jsp:

```
             <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="cat">
                <tr>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="catrgo" value="${category}"
                            label="${cat.categoryId}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${cat.category}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

And In HomeController:
           @Controller
            @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
           public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm() {
    FeedDomain feedDomain = new FeedDomain();

    System.out.println("Called");
    CategoryService categoryService = new CategoryService();
    try {
        List<CategoryDomain> categoryDomainList = new   ArrayList<CategoryDomain>();
        CategoryDomain categoryDomain = new CategoryDomain();
        categoryDomain.setCategory("aaa");
        categoryDomain.setCategoryId(11111);

        System.out.println("Size is " + categoryDomainList.size());
    } catch (Exception exception) {

    }
    return "home";
}
```

Now I am going to home.jsp from index.jsp using  tags but the problem is that showForm method is not getting called. What can be the reason?

I am posting below the complete flow:

Here is welcome.jsp from where I am calling home.jsp

```
       <body>
             <a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-success btn-large disabled">Get
                        Us Feeds Now</a>
       </body>
```

Now  I have simplified home.jsp which is getting rendered:

```
    <body>

<br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="badge badge-info"><h1>Chat Booster</h1></span>
<div class="leftHeader">
    <h1>
        <small>Subtext for header</small>
    </h1>
</div>
<br></br>
<br></br>

    </body>
```

And home page controller is :

```
         @Controller
        @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm() {
    FeedDomain feedDomain = new FeedDomain();
//  model.addAttribute("feedDomain", feedDomain);
    System.out.println("Called");
    CategoryService categoryService = new CategoryService();

    return "home";
}
```

web.xml:

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>HelloWorldExampleWithSpring3MVCInEclipse</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-  class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

app-config.xml:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
    directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
    </beans>
```

**My jsp pages are in webcontent folder only (not in web-inf).** Now I will look for the main issue later but first point is showForm() method is not being called as sysouts are not priting anything at console. If I make home.jsp as default page of the application, then the method is called but not through the given approach. Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: Do you have the ViewResolver set up correctly?

Comment: this part look like a mistake: `value="${category}"` there is no category in your code defined.

Comment: ViewResolver should be fine as pages are getting rendered properly. And I have even removed checkbox code from jsp page but still showForm() is not being called.

Comment: I have added the entire flow to make things easier to understand. Please help me out here.

Comment: You don't need to use jsp paths in  your code - the controller has mapping to `/home`, not `/home.jsp` - please show the respective mapping to the `DispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`. 
showForm() is not called because you're trying to access `/home.jsp` instead of `/home` - it's unlikely that you want to access the jsp files directly without using Spring MVC.

Comment: I have posted the code showing mapping of DispatcherServlet in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your link is incorrect, you need to call the controller action not the jsp:

```
   <body>
       <c:url var="homeLink" value="/home"/>
       <a href="${homeLink}" class="btn btn-success btn-large disabled">Get Us Feeds Now</a>
   </body>
```

Comment: I have tried the same but now the link is taking the user to the same welcome.jsp page. I am not able to go to home.jsp. I have added web.xml and app-config.xml in the code.

Comment: I have tried many examples given in forums and every example is same as I have written. So why I am not going to home.jsp after clicking the link? Can anyone comment on this?